# installing anaconda broke flask-security db.session.commit()

Tags: anaconda, flask-sqlalchemy

I noticed when I installed anaconda it broke all of my updates using db.session.commit. However, it would stall add records just fine. I found a way around it using merge, but I am not seasoned enough to work around some of the scenarios.

Prior to installing anaconda the following would work;

```
u = Users.query.get(1)
u.name = 'John Doe'
db.session.commit()
```

After installing anaconda I have to use the following;

```
u = Users.query.get(1)
u.name = 'John Doe'
db.session.merge(u)
db.session.commit()
```

now, here is my problem. here is my models.db (adapting the flask mega tutorial for my purposes)

```
followers = db.Table('followers',
    db.Column('follower_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id')),
    db.Column('followed_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
)

class Users(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(30))

    posts = db.relationship('usersPosts', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')   

    followed = db.relationship(
        'Users', secondary=followers,
        primaryjoin=(followers.c.follower_id == id),
        secondaryjoin=(followers.c.followed_id == id),
        backref=db.backref('followers', lazy='dynamic'), lazy='dynamic')

    def follow(self, user):
        if not self.is_following(user):
            self.followed.append(user)

    def unfollow(self, user):
        if self.is_following(user):
            self.followed.remove(user)
```

however, I cannot find a syntax that will work for the following;

```
usr = Users.query.filter_by(email = 'xzy@gmail.com').first()
cusr = Users.query.filter_by(email = 'xzy@yahoo.com').first()
cusr.unfollow(usr)
db.session.commit()
```

Ideally I could figure out what is breaking the updates and set a configuration somewhere, but I have been unable to figure that out. A working alternative would be a workaround for the code above.

Comment: I am feeling a little sheepish about this solution, but I will post it anyway (rather I created this problem myself). It seemed like the updates were not going to the session. When I was originally creating this project, and getting my feet wet with the blueprints, I was getting an error I could not work around. I added `db = SQLAlchemy()` to models.py. Well, apparently I had also added it to my main __init__.py. So basically I did have 2 session. I deleted it from models.py and everything is working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use db.session.add before commit:

```
db.session.add(u)
db.session.commit()
```

Comment: I had `db = SQLAlchemy()` in 2 different files (my __init__.py and my m9dels.py) so basically I had 2 sessions.